# With a Bootstrap Modal, can you restrict the fading of the page to a parent div of the page, and not to the whole body?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a small game and I need to make a modal appear in the game "window" (a div) and the rest of the window to fade and gray out, but not the whole page, where the interface remains.

Is there a simple way to restrict this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to use Bootstrap Modal? If so it will take some hackery to get it working properly. But it can certainly be done. You would need to:

1. Change where the backdrop is inserted. Boostrap Modal will append the backdrop to the document.body, so you'd have to change the js file to append to (or probably insert into) the div you wanted to cover.
2. the css would need to be changed also. Currently, the backdrop styling just uses a fixed position to cover the entire window (edges at 0, 0, 0. 0). You'd want it to cover just a div which would mean changing from fixed width to something else.
3. The css of the modal might have to change, depending on where you wanted it centred etc.

Maybe you could try Element blocking with BlockUI. This seems to have what you want built in?

http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#element

Id not that, then there are many examples of blocking or covering sections of a page for loading and ajaxy type operations. I would look into one of those.

Comment: Hey @SimonC thanks for the tips, unsurprisingly it's more complicated than I thought, I might have to code my own version of the modal (I'm using meteor.js for this). BlockUI can most certainly help !