# BootStrap Modal dialogue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone tell me the way to handle below scenario?
I have one screen that have header, left-pane and have content area which is DIV with some content like buttons ,textboxes etc so when I click on one icon inside content area, a dialogue is displayed which is being displayed using bootstrap. When dialog is shown it blocked complete screen instead we need to block only content area..

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [With a Bootstrap Modal, can you restrict the fading of the page to a parent div of the page, and not to the whole body?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187308/with-a-bootstrap-modal-can-you-restrict-the-fading-of-the-page-to-a-parent-div)

Comment: can you add some code or fiddle so we can understand what you are trying to say!

Comment: Code is quite complex. I will you explain more deeply.Suppose I have master page that contain menu in header and also one left pane that contains some links. I have a content page that uses master page and have button ,textboxes etc. So when I click on button a modal dialogue is opened using bootstrap that will block(grayed out) the whole page including menu and left pane. So what I want is menu and left pane should work even dialogue box is open.